# What is the order of operations for set complements?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, notation, operator-theory

Suppose I have something like:

$A\backslash B\backslash C$

Does that mean $(A\backslash B)\backslash C$ *,elements in A, but neither in B nor C*

Or does it mean $A\backslash(B\backslash C)$ *,elements in A not in B, unless they are also in C*

As always, creating such a construction is a bad idea, as it is always best to state what you mean clearly, but in what order would chained set complements be interpreted?

Comment: This example demonstrates the importance for the person who creates notation to see if there is a way that reasonable people could disagree on what the notation means.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure, but it would make perfect sense to treat the relative complement operator as left-associative.

When we say $A - B - C$ for numbers, we never expect it to mean $A - (B - C)$, unless specifically written that way.

If you're defining it yourself, say in a programming language, then of course it depends on your intention, which should ideally reflect in your grammar.

<*compl*>$ \ \rightarrow$ <*set*> <*compl-chain*>

<*compl-chain*> $ \ \rightarrow$ \ <*set*> | \ <*set*> <*compl-chain*>

The parse tree for this grammar would be leaning to the right, so the most intuitive evaluation would be right-associative.

Comment: Many such "anti-commutative" operations are always defined as left associative. It's still an interesting thought.